# Daily return volatility in large panel data

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have a large matrix with daily returns in wide format for which I want to compute daily volatilities in a time-varying window [-1;-251].

I use the the following code:

```
n=1000
m=500
ret=matrix(rnorm(n*m,mean=0,sd=1), n, m) 
vola=matrix(0, n, m) 
start.time = Sys.time()

for (j in 1: ncol(ret)){
  for (i in 251:nrow(ret)){
    vola[i,j]=sd(ret[(i-1):(i-251+1),j])*sqrt(251)}
}
end.time = Sys.time()
time.taken = end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

However, it takes too long:

```
Time difference of 8.242027 secs
```

My original data takes 15 minutes.

I found the following piece of code which I believe to perform faster:

```
my.rollapply <- function(vec, width, FUN) 
  lapply(1:nrow(vec), 
         function(i) if (i < width) NA else FUN(vec[(i-1):(i-width+1),1]))
```

on [Moving variance in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195442/moving-variance-in-r)

but I haven't figured out how to apply it to a matrix.

Any help (maybe vectorization works as well?) to speed up the process is highly appreciated.

EDIT: It would be great if we could stick to base R.

Comment: Have a look at `roll_sd(...)` in package `RccpRoll`. This should be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the comment.

`rollapply(...)` is very convenient but not very fast. `roll_sd(...)` from the `RccpRoll` package is much faster.

```
library(RcppRoll)
df <- as.data.frame(ret)
system.time(result<- sapply(df, function(x) roll_sd(x,n=251)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.94    0.00    0.95
```

Comment: It is not base R but I like the speed of the function. Thanks!